# Snappydata cannot have an array of size more than 1000

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snappydata

Can anyone help me and provide me info regarding the limit of array length and dimensions a row/column table's row can have. I cannot add more than 1000 elements to my array. Is there any way to increase its size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you get the data from file?
Try to check the size of array in file.
Snappy supports array size more than 1000.

Answer (score 2):

Snappydata is not supporting anything more than thousand columns for either of row tables or column tables.
https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata/issues/769